# Azure Spatial Anchors - Getting Cloud Spatial Exception on HoloLens

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm getting an CloudSpatialException while trying to create an anchor. Already created an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/161) on github for.

**The guide I'm following:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-asa-ch1

**What I already did:**

1. Capabilities are set in unity and in the solution via visual studio (→Package.appxmanifest)
2. HoloLens is updated
3. Credentials are set the right way; took the *Account ID* and *Primary key*
4. Added `<DeviceCapability Name="wiFiControl"/>` to `Package.appxmanifest`
5. Storage permissions are set in capabilities

**My specs:**
Unity 2019.2.15
MRTK 2.2
AzureSpatialAnchors.unitypackage
MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.2.0.0.unitypackage
MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.GettingStarted.2.2.0.1.unitypackage

**My Log:**

```
AnchorModuleScript.StartAzureSession()
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<LoadSceneCoRoutine>d__3:System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.UIBehaviour:IsDestroyed()
AnchorModuleScript:StartAzureSession()
DeleteASAAnchorDelegate:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:SendOnClick(IMixedRealityPointer)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:OnInputUp(InputEventData)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.<>c:<.cctor>b__196_18(IMixedRealityBaseInputHandler, BaseEventData)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.AnchorLocatedDelegate:Invoke(Object, AnchorLocatedEventArgs)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:ExecuteHierarchy(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSystem:DispatchEventToObjectFocusedByPointer(IMixedRealityPointer, BaseInputEventData, Boolean, EventFunction`1)
...

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Starting Azure session... please wait...
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<LoadSceneCoRoutine>d__3:System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.UIBehaviour:IsDestroyed()
AnchorModuleScript:StartAzureSession()
DeleteASAAnchorDelegate:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:SendOnClick(IMixedRealityPointer)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:OnInputUp(InputEventData)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.<>c:<.cctor>b__196_18(IMixedRealityBaseInputHandler, BaseEventData)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.AnchorLocatedDelegate:Invoke(Object, AnchorLocatedEventArgs)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:ExecuteHierarchy(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSystem:DispatchEventToObjectFocusedByPointer(IMixedRealityPointer, BaseInputEventData, Boolean, EventFunction`1)
...

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Azure session started successfully
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<LoadSceneCoRoutine>d__3:System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:InvokeMoveNext(Object)
System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:Run()
DeleteASAAnchorDelegate:Invoke()
System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation:RunCallback(ContextCallback, Object, Task&)
System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation:Run(Task, Boolean)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishStageThree()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult(TResult)
WinRT.Interop._IAsyncOperation`2:.ctor(Guid, ObjectReference`1)
WinRT.Interop._IAsyncOperation`2:.ctor(Guid, ObjectReference`1)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1:Create()
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.TokenRequiredEventArgs:set_AuthenticationToken(String)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:InvokeMoveNext(Object)
...

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

AnchorModuleScript.CreateAzureAnchor()
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<BlipTargetCoroutine>d__7:System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.UIBehaviour:IsDestroyed()
AnchorModuleScript:CreateAzureAnchor(GameObject)
System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
UnityEngine.Events.CachedInvokableCall`1:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:SendOnClick(IMixedRealityPointer)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:OnInputUp(InputEventData)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.<>c:<.cctor>b__196_18(IMixedRealityBaseInputHandler, BaseEventData)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.AnchorLocatedDelegate:Invoke(Object, AnchorLocatedEventArgs)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:ExecuteHierarchy(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSystem:DispatchEventToObjectFocusedByPointer(IMixed...

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Local anchor created
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<BlipTargetCoroutine>d__7:System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.UIBehaviour:IsDestroyed()
AnchorModuleScript:CreateAzureAnchor(GameObject)
System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
UnityEngine.Events.CachedInvokableCall`1:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:SendOnClick(IMixedRealityPointer)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:OnInputUp(InputEventData)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.<>c:<.cctor>b__196_18(IMixedRealityBaseInputHandler, BaseEventData)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.AnchorLocatedDelegate:Invoke(Object, AnchorLocatedEventArgs)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
...

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Creating Azure anchor... please wait...
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<BlipTargetCoroutine>d__7:System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.UIBehaviour:IsDestroyed()
AnchorModuleScript:CreateAzureAnchor(GameObject)
System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
UnityEngine.Events.CachedInvokableCall`1:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:SendOnClick(IMixedRealityPointer)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable:OnInputUp(InputEventData)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.<>c:<.cctor>b__196_18(IMixedRealityBaseInputHandler, BaseEventData)
...

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.CloudSpatialException
  at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.NativeLibraryHelpers.CheckStatus (System.IntPtr handle, Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.status value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.CloudSpatialAnchorSession+<>c__DisplayClass79_0.<CreateAnchorAsync>b__0 () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at AnchorModuleScript+DeleteASAAnchorDelegate.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task& currentTaskSlot) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry (System.Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Create () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at EyeTrackingTutorialDemo+<BlipTargetCoroutine>d__7.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (System.Object stateMachine) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at AnchorModuleScript+DeleteASAAnchorDelegate.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation+<>c.<.cctor>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.WSA.WindowSizeChanged.BeginInvoke (System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object object) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Create () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.TokenRequiredEventArgs.set_AuthenticationToken (System.String value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (System.Object stateMachine) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at AnchorModuleScript+DeleteASAAnchorDelegate.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback (System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task& currentTask) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.Run (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Boolean canInlineContinuationTask) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish (System.Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].TrySetException (System.Object exceptionObject) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.Interop._IAsyncOperation`2[TTask,TResult]..ctor (System.Guid iid, WinRT.ObjectReference`1[T] obj) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[TResult].Create () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at EyeTrackingTutorialDemo+<BlipTargetCoroutine>d__7.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (System.Object stateMachine) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at AnchorModuleScript+DeleteASAAnchorDelegate.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation+<>c.<.cctor>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.WSA.WindowSizeChanged.BeginInvoke (System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object object) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Create () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at EyeTrackingTutorialDemo+<BlipTargetCoroutine>d__7.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (System.Object stateMachine) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at AnchorModuleScript+DeleteASAAnchorDelegate.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback (System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task& currentTask) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.Run (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Boolean canInlineContinuationTask) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish (System.Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].TrySetException (System.Object exceptionObject) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.Interop._IAsyncOperation`2[TTask,TResult]..ctor (System.Guid iid, WinRT.ObjectReference`1[T] obj) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[TResult].Create () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.TokenRequiredEventArgs.set_AuthenticationToken (System.String value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (System.Object stateMachine) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at AnchorModuleScript+DeleteASAAnchorDelegate.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback (System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task& currentTask) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.Run (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Boolean canInlineContinuationTask) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish (System.Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].TrySetException (System.Object exceptionObject) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WinRT.Interop._IAsyncOperation`2[TTask,TResult]..ctor (System.Guid iid, WinRT.ObjectReference`1[T] obj) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[TResult].Create () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at EyeTrackingTutorialDemo+<BlipTargetCoroutine>d__7.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (System.Object stateMachine) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at AnchorModuleScript+DeleteASAAnchorDelegate.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation+<>c.<.cctor>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.Invoke (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.WSA.WindowSizeChanged.BeginInvoke (System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object object) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<BlipTargetCoroutine>d__7:System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:InvokeMoveNext(Object)
System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:Run()
DeleteASAAnchorDelegate:Invoke()
System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation:RunCallback(ContextCallback, Object, Task&)
System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation:Run(Task, Boolean)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishStageThree()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishStageTwo()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:Finish(Boolean)
...

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue was fixed by Microsoft. Got the answer from Ramon Arguelles on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/161#issuecomment-619260992):
*We recently discovered and fixed a bug in our Azure Spatial Anchor service that may have been the reason behind the issue you are seeing.*